# OpenGl 3.3 on Raspberry Pi 4 8gb

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

Run OpenGl 3.3 on Raspberry Pi

Good evening,
When I run Blender (I don’t know, I suggest it is Blender 2.8 (in Ubuntu), because in normal Raspbain OS, with Blender 2.79 it works out) with my Raspberry Pi 4 8 gb, there is a warning:

```
    [![Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.][1]][1]
```

There is a picture of this code (Is needed, because I would like to show that in Ubuntu it is different)
[image: Picture of the code written above]

Or another example: When I start Supertuxkartracer, there is also a Warning:
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
[image]

Therefore I suggest that running OpenGl 3.3 is needed, so I did a lot of research on the internet, but did not find a resolution.

I have the question:
Is there any solution to install OpenGl 3.3?

Comment: What are this pictures showing? Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Comment: Even if you intend to show differences between two systems, there's no need for screenshots. Post two text logs.

Comment: Not on Ubintu but on Kali you can install Blender! Video tutorial: [How to install blender 2.8 on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x3QURLpTaI)

Answer (score 7):

OpenGL is not just a software library, it's a software interface to hardware features of the graphics accelerator. While it's technically possible to emulate a higher version of OpenGL on a weak hardware (by implementing the missing functions in software) there's little point in doing so, because such compatibility will come at the expense of performance.

Currently Pi 4 is limited to OpenGL 2.1

If you're a technical type, you can generate an OpenGL 3.3 wrapper using [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) and see how far the Pi's hardware (which supports EGL 1.5 under the hood) will take you. I assume the whole reason OpenGL 2.1 was chosen for the Pi is because you won't get any additional hardware-implemented features if you go for a higher version. Having an OpenGL 3.3 library which in fact only supports a functional subset corresponding to OpenGL 2.1 will result in a failure later down the road when Blender will try to use any of the non-implemented features.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable [mesa3d](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html) software rendering.

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true blender
```

Then it will work, but you won't be able to do any serious work for now, hopefully soon. You could play with custom builds of mesa3d, though.

EDIT: This is why it works on Kali Linux.